# making newsletter(HTML) with SpringFramework3

Tags: html, css, spring, jsp, newsletter

I am sending newsletter like below with Springframework 3.

```
private void sendMail(Map<String,Object> mailInfo) throws Exception{
    JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
    mailSender.setHost("smtp.myhost.com");
    mailSender.setPort(587);
    mailSender.setUsername("email@email.com");
    mailSender.setPassword("12345");

    MimeMessage msg = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
    MimeMessageHelper mHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(msg, true, "UTF-8");

    mHelper.setFrom(new InternetAddress(
            mailInfo.get("send_mail").toString(), mailInfo.get("send_name").toString()));
    mHelper.setTo(new InternetAddress(
            mailInfo.get("recv_mail").toString(), mailInfo.get("recv_name").toString()));

    mHelper.setText(mailInfo.get("mail_desc").toString(), true);
    mHelper.setSubject(mailInfo.get("mail_title").toString());

    mailSender.send(msg);
}
```

In my case value of `mail_desc` is an HTML(it has css and other resources). Mail goes well, but its CSS and all of images are broken.

I appended to all of src value like below in JSP

```
function getDomain(){
    var DNS = location.href;
    DNS = DNS.split('//');
    DNS = 'http://' + DNS[1].substr(0,DNS[1].indexOf("/"));
    return DNS;
}
```

So When I print this in browser console it returns `localhost:8080/myApp/{image_src}`.
However, When I open with gmail it looks quite different. it looks like...

```
<img src="https://ci5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/FVJ1IBTWmX0l0KPlNQVY_AkDsCL02O2Y_kZS7KACQlnXgfgNvNQvjBKpn9zIdPH84N_r-ulunXvzlMCVUOWsMG1WCjfYUFVX7VpjJ5OV5RdpV2ReZFjM9Yw=s0-d-e1-ft#http://localhost:8080/resources/gtl_portal/images/newsletter/ci.png" alt="ci" class="CToWUd">
```

Now I got questions like below :

- How to implement newsletter in Normal? Where can I find some examples or references?(I think this can solve lots of problem here)
- How to change value things looks like. it is quite tricky, since it is embedded in style attribute.:

  ```
  <td height="50px" style="background:url('/resources/images/newsletter/top_bg.png') repeat-x 0 0;padding:15px">
  ```

Thanks a lot :D bb

Comment: Note that Gmail prefetches images to prevent marketers from tracking when messages are opened, and it rewrites image URLs accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant include your external css like you do normally , but you can prefer the way of wrapping the styles in the inline way (in `<head>` tag). So something like this,

```
<style>
.bigFont{
font-size:14px;
}
<style>
<body>
<p class='bigFont' >Hi , i am bigger </p>
</body>
```

so this looks separate instead adding style attribute to your tags , you can also avoid some code by resusing .

AFAIK , for adding inline images [Spring framework](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mail.html) has very good documentation. It is supported widely by mail clients, an example,

```
FileSystemResource res = new FileSystemResource(new File("c:/Sample.jpg"));
helper.addInline("identifier1234", res);
```

so that you can simply use it as `<img src='cid:identifier1234'>`.

For advanced templating options you can integrate your web app with [Apache velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/), a templating library

Comment: Thanks. But It has a problem to apply your solution. first, I read whole HTML(additionally, it does not import external css, but uses external images) and get this as a String value in Spring. So it is not easy to replace image source to other like what you said. are there alternative ways to do this?(I hope I can handle this in HTML level...).Thanks

Comment: Yes you need to handle it in the `html` level . No other native solutions from the framework

Comment: Sorry, I can not get exactly what you mean `No other native solutions from the framework`, Since Code above here is Java code, not only HTML. Now, Main issue revealed that is how linking image in HTML not CSS. Thanks for kind answer and sorry for my English^^;;

Comment: Oh! Thanks. It was my mistake. I just put wrong src String in img tag.