# Implementing newletter with jsp and gmail issues

Tags: html, image, jsp, email, gmail

I implemented newsletter with Spring3 and jsp.

referencing post link : [making newsletter(HTML) with SpringFramework3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27119865/making-newsletterhtml-with-springframework3)

Now It works nice except on gmail, outlook.

I found that this issue is famous but there was no clear solution in web.

I am suffered with `src` attribute of image tag.

Here is a original tag which is working on other mail client(?)

```
<img style="width:322px;height:196px; display:block;" src="http://localhost:8080/resources/portal/images/virtual/noimg02.jpg">
```

However, when I send it to gmail, it transferred like :

```
<img style="width:322px;min-height:196px;display:block" src="https://ci5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/eC8FaWQmdUqkQoquMqW3NKl_u14NwS5bgKPb9_36kgfUc0t9FM8Rm9Q_BDvjN3flSnFJOU_CNW8vn8wjrtB0HNVWVk1i6y9dTIAaNa78zjki7Kl7XNqsKs1ThA=s0-d-e1-ft#http://localhost:8080/resources/portal/images/virtual/noimg02.jpg" class="CToWUd">
```

sorry for `localhost:8080`, since we do not prepared ant development servers yet.

How to prevent auto wrapping like that in gmail.

I have already change my Image options of gmail(allow external image link), but it does not work.

Thanks for your answer :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It found that google do some validation job.
However, in my case, (my dev environment) network allows only internal access, so
it can not show proper image.

I switched network from internal network to wifi, it works fine :D
I hope this could be help to others.